# Where to put image files for Javadoc?

Tags: java, image, javadoc

I know I can use `IMG` tag in javadoc. But where to put image files? If I put them along with java files, they will go to `JAR` file or `class` folder during compiling, which is not required.

How to have image files which relate with javadoc only, not with code resources?

Comment: Never used it, but I guess using the [docfilessubdirs option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#docfilessubdirs) and specifying an additional [sourcepath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#sourcepath) containing the parent directory of the docfiles directory would work fine.

Answer (score 2):

As specified in the [Javadoc tool documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#unprocessed), in the "Miscellaneous Unprocessed Files" section:

> To include unprocessed files, put them in a directory called doc-files
>   which can be a subdirectory of any package directory that contains
>   source files. You can have one such subdirectory for each package. You
>   might include images, example code, source files, .class files,
>   applets and HTML files. For example, if you want to include the image
>   of a button button.gif in the java.awt.Button class documentation, you
>   place that file in the /home/user/src/java/awt/doc-files/ directory.
>   Notice the doc-files directory should not be located at
>   /home/user/src/java/doc-files because java is not a package -- that
>   is, it does not directly contain any source files.

This means that the image files have to be provided as part of the source directory structure. The implication is that your build process should be designed to avoid copying those files to the classes directory structure. The raw `javac` tool does not do the copy, and you would have to configure either your IDE or build script (maven, ant, gradle, etc.) to exclude these files in the compilation or jar step.

Comment: How to refer image in `doc-files` with `IMG` tag? With relative path or what?

Comment: @Dims, yes, use a path relative to the root of the source directory

Comment: Start the path from "/" or from "./"?